# How to count the amount of each word in my sql database?

Tags: mysql, sql

My goal is to make a function that retrieves the top ten "tags". I know I need to use the count(*) function in SQL and order by that count descending, then limit to 10 results.(I currently only have 2)
My current database has 3 tags of "apple" and 2 tags of "tree"(examples)

My sql statement currently is

```
SELECT count(*) FROM database.tags **where** ? order by count(*) desc;
```

I am unsure as to how I should make my where statement to retrieve the tags in order where I would see something returned looking a bit similar to

```
Apple count(3) , Tree count(2)
(using MySQL workbench)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you want `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT t.tag, COUNT(*)
FROM database.tags t
GROUP BY t.tag
ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thank You! A bit new to this :)

Comment: Also, is there a way for the same statement to return the other field? As currently it only returns 3,2 when I would like to also get what is in the tag field to show.

Comment: @JackGab . . . That is what `SELECT t.tag` is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Alright thank you for the help, I had tried * instead and was producing errors. Have a good night!